# Android bottom navigation bar visibility

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

How can I make the bottom Navigation bar appear on selected activities and don't appear on others ?
What lines should I add to make it happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**bottom Navigation bar** is also a view in your some layout file, you could do like this:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                    findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //In activity you want to hide it
    bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //In activity you want to show it
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: you are welcome, could you upvote or accept my answer, thanks!